# How to configure tasks in symfony 1.4?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I've used `symfony 1.4` and `Doctrine` to build a sort of mini-CMS. It uses a database to store the different pages and categories.

Now I've added another connection to `databases.yml`, in order to retrieve client info.

I would like to indicate to `symfony` that that database is **read-only**, and that it should never ever write to it.

For the moment, I've created a user on the 2nd database that can only read, it seems to do the trick even though commands like `doctrine:build --all` still try to write in it.

**EDIT :** Thanks to Pascal's answer, I use events to tell doctrine to use only one db for the task `sfDoctrineDropDbTask`.

```
  public function setup()
  {
    (...)
    $this->dispatcher->connect('command.filter_options', array($this, 'filterCommandOptions'));
  }

  public function filterCommandOptions(sfEvent $event, $options)
  {

    if ('sfDoctrineDropDbTask' === get_class($event->getSubject()))
      $options = array('base1');
    elseif ('sfDoctrineBuildDbTask' === get_class($event->getSubject()))
      $options = array('base1');

    elseif ('sfDoctrineDataDumpTask' === get_class($event->getSubject()))
      $options = array('base1');
    //elseif ('sfDoctrineInsertSqlTask' === get_class($event->getSubject()))
      //$options = array('base1');
    elseif ('sfDoctrineCreateModelTables' === get_class($event->getSubject()))
      $options = array('base1');


    return $options;
  }
```

This trick does not seem to work for the other tasks :

- `doctrine:data-dump` still reads both databases,
- doctrine still tries to write during a `doctrine:build --all` task
- `sfDoctrineInsertSqlTask` complains that I gave too many options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could force the name of the database doctrine:build --all can drop using events.

check this : https://gist.github.com/582306

Comment: Very nice, symfony no longers try to drop the db ! Where can I find other command name, like "sfDoctrineDropDbTask" ?